# How to create data.table with different size of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I create data.table like this.

```
DT = data.table(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

But I get this result.

```
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 2 2
3: 3 3
4: 1 4
5: 2 5
```

but I'd like to get this.

```
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 2 2
3: 3 3
4: NA 4
5: NA 5
```

How can I create data.table with different size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
install.packages("qpcR")
library(qpcR)

df <- data.table(qpcR:::cbind.na(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3,4,5)))
  A B
1  1 1
2  2 2
3  3 3
4 NA 4
5 NA 5
```

Comment: totally fine as a one-off, but keep in mind that using unexported functions is riskier

Answer (score 7):

We keep the `vector` of unequal length in a `list` ('lst'), then loop through the `list` elements, append NA at the end and convert to `data.table`.

```
lst <- list(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3,4,5))
DT <- setDT(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))[]
DT
#    A B
#1:  1 1
#2:  2 2
#3:  3 3
#4: NA 4
#5: NA 5
```

Comment: Nice and clever, I never think of assignments inside *apply functions :c

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a wrapper that, instead of recycling elements, adds `NA` values at the end of each vector so that the length of all input vectors are the same:

```
data.table2 <- function(...) {

  args <- list(...)
  max_length <- max(sapply(args, length))
  foo <- function(x) {
    y <- rep(NA, max_length - length(x))
    return(c(x, y))
  }
  new_args <- lapply(args, foo)
  do.call(data.table, new_args)

}

data.table2(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3,4,5))

> DT
    A B
1:  1 1
2:  2 2
3:  3 3
4: NA 4
5: NA 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very extensible, but this works as well:

```
data.table(A = 1:3)[ , I := .I][data.table(B = 1:5)[ , I := .I], on = "I"]

#     A I B
# 1:  1 1 1
# 2:  2 2 2
# 3:  3 3 3
# 4: NA 4 4
# 5: NA 5 5
```

(append `[ , I := NULL]` to remove the added column)